# How can I make a Spring Boot JpaRepository repository method pegeable?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working on a Spring Boot using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate and I have the following problem trying to make pageable a repository method.

If I use method such as **findAll()** it is pretty simple to make it pegaeable. For example I have this service method where I call the **findAll()** repository method passing to it the **Pageable** object:

```
@Override
public Page<WalletDTO> getAllWalletsList(Pageable pageable) throws NotFoundException {
    
    Page<Wallet> walletsList = this.walletRepository.findAll(pageable);
    
    if(walletsList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(String.format("There are no wallet in the whole system !!!"));
    }
        
    return walletsList.map(m -> conversionService.convert(m, WalletDTO.class));

}
```

It works perfectly.

But now I have this repository interface:

```
public interface WalletRepository extends JpaRepository<Wallet, Integer> {
    
    List<Wallet> findByUser_Id(Integer id);
    
    List<Wallet> findByWalletType_Name(String walletName);
    
    List<Wallet> findByWalletType_WalletType(WalletType walletType, Pageable pageable);
    
    Wallet findByAddress(String address);   

}
```

What can I do to make a method pegeable, I was trying to do something like this:

```
List<Wallet> findByWalletType_WalletType(WalletType walletType, Pageable pageable);
```

but I don't know if it could be a solution. What could be the correct way to implement this behavior?

Comment: It isn't **a solution** it is **the solution**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

> We also provide persistence technology-specific abstractions, such as
> JpaRepository or MongoRepository. **Those interfaces extend
> CrudRepository and expose the capabilities of the underlying
> persistence** technology in addition to the rather generic persistence
> technology-agnostic interfaces such as CrudRepository.
>
> On top of the CrudRepository, there is a **PagingAndSortingRepository**
> abstraction that adds additional methods to ease paginated access to
> entities

So by extending `JpaRepository` you already have inhereted `PagingAndSortingRepository` and you can expose methods with pagination, which will be automatically implemented by Spring.

Also according to [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) you have the following examples that will automatically be implemented by Spring data JPA

> Example 14. Using Pageable, Slice, and Sort in query methods
>
> Page findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
>
> Slice findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
>
> List findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

So in your case you would have the following options

```
Page<Wallet> findByWalletType_WalletType(WalletType walletType, Pageable pageable);

Slice<Wallet> findByWalletType_WalletType(WalletType walletType, Pageable pageable);

List<Wallet> findByWalletType_WalletType(WalletType walletType, Pageable pageable);
```

Read the doc for more details, pick the one you prefer and you should be good!

Just one last tip. For your already declared name `WalletType_WalletType` to work it means that `Wallet` has a field named `WalletType` and then `WalletType` has also a field with name `WalletType`. This seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, instead of returning your type directly, you may either return a `Page<T>` or a `Slice<T>`. The main difference being that the page will trigger an additional count (useful for displaying a pager for example) while the slice is only aware of being the last (useful for an infinite scroll).